# ImportError: No module named pox.core

Tags: python

This is code

`from pox.core import core`
`import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of`
`from pox.lib.util import dpidToStr`
`log = core.getLogger()`

I already install pox but sitll getting this error

Comment: Actually I am doing program for SDN controller, for that code run through linux terminal. I installed pox with `pip install pox`. I am not using anaconda.

Comment: By using pip3 earlier error resolved, but got new error `ImportError: No module named core`

Answer (score 2):

POX requires Python 2.7 which can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by the following command:

```
sudo apt install python2.7
```

Optionally you can also install pip for Python 2.7 with `sudo apt install python-pip`. If you need to install Java separately, the command to install the compatible Java version is `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

To start the python2.7 interpreter from the terminal type `python`

For more information visit the [SDN Hub Pox Controller Tutorial](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/pox/).